# Using Circe to decode Json String

Tags: json, scala, decode, circe

I have a Json string as

```
val configInfo =   {
      "car": {
        "requesters": {
          "request1": "key1",
          "request2": "key2"
        },
        "provider": {
          "request1": "key3",
          "request2": "key4"
        }
      },
      "truck": {
        "requesters": {
          "request1": "key2",
          "request2": "key3"
        },
        "provider": {
          "request1": "key2",
          "request2": "key3"
        }
      }
    }
```

I have the following case class to decode json string.

```
final case class TenantSettings(requesters: Map[String, String], provider: Map[String, String] = Map.empty)
```

Also, providers in above case class is optional, it may or may not be present in json string.

I want to decode this using circe to

```
val value = decode[Map[String, TenantSettings]](configInfo)
```

I understand I need to use custom circe codec, but I am unable to do it, Can someone please help out on this.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I corrected the code

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am stuck with writing custom code too since its map since map. I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a custom codec. You only need to need to configure the derived codec using [**circe-generic-extras**](https://github.com/circe/circe-generic-extras).

So given:

```
val configInfo =
    """{
        "car": {
          "requesters": {
            "request1": "key1",
            "request2": "key2"
          },
          "provider": {
            "request1": "key3",
            "request2": "key4"
          }
        },
        "truck": {
          "requesters": {
            "request1": "key2",
            "request2": "key3"
          },
          "provider": {
            "request1": "key2",
            "request2": "key3"
          }
        },
        "blah": {
          "requesters": {
            "request1": "key2"
          }
        }
      }"""
```

You can:

```
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration
import io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto.deriveConfiguredDecoder

final case class TenantSettings(requesters: Map[String, String], provider: Map[String, String] = Map.empty)
object TentantSettings {
  private implicit final val customConfig: Configuration = Configuration.default.withDefaults
  implicit final val TenantSettingsDecoder: Decoder[TenantSettings] = deriveConfiguredDecoder
}
```

And then:

```
io.circe.parser.decode[Map[String, TenantSettings]](configInfo)
// res: Either[io.circe.Error, Map[String, TenantSettings]] = Right(
//   Map(
//     "car" -> TenantSettings(Map("request1" -> "key1", "request2" -> "key2"), Map("request1" -> "key3", "request2" -> "key4")),
//     "truck" -> TenantSettings(Map("request1" -> "key2", "request2" -> "key3"), Map("request1" -> "key2", "request2" -> "key3")),
//     "blah" -> TenantSettings(Map("request1" -> "key2"), Map())
//   )
// )
```

Comment: I get the following error

could not find Lazy implicit value of type io.circe.generic.extras.decoding.ConfiguredDecoder[A]
[error]   implicit final val decodeTenantSettings: Decoder[TenantSettings] = deriveConfiguredDecoder

I have wartRemover in my project that is catching this issue

Comment: @ArjunKarnwal If you disable it? does the code compiles? BTW, try adding `-Ywarn-macros:after` to your **scalac** options.

Comment: Actually, I am wrong. Wart is not enable but I am still getting this error. :(

Comment: @ArjunKarnwal Is your code different from the one in the question and are you sure you made everything I did in my answer? Also, which Scala version and circe version are you using?

Comment: scala version 2.13 and circe 0.13.0

Comment: Yes actually, I did make a change.
`final case class TenantSettings(requesters: Map[String, String], provider: Map[String, String] = Map.empty)Map[String, String] = Map.empty)`

is changed to

`type TenantSettings = Map[String, String]`

Comment: if I change from type to case class, I do not see that error.

Comment: @ArjunKarnwal Well, that code was made for a case class not for a map... if your problem is different, please open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Circe provides all `Decoder` instances you need except the one for `TenantSettings` since it's a custom type. `Map` and `String` are no problem.

`circe-generic-extras` or `circe-derivation` are very useful to generate `Decoder` instances for case classes. In this case you want to enable "defaults" in the config, so it falls back to the empty map instead of failing.

Here's the code:

```scala
// you need circe-core, circe-parser and circe-generic-extras as dependencies
import io.circe._
import io.circe.parser.decode
import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration
import io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto._

val configInfo = """{
    "car": {
      "requesters": {
        "request1": "key1",
        "request2": "key2"
      },
      "provider": {
        "request1": "key3",
        "request2": "key4"
      }
    },
    "truck": {
      "requesters": {
        "request1": "key2",
        "request2": "key3"
      },
      "provider": {
        "request1": "key2",
        "request2": "key3"
      }
    }
  }
  """

final case class TenantSettings(
  requesters: Map[String, String],
  provider: Map[String, String] = Map.empty
)
object TenantSettings {
  implicit private val derivationConfig: Configuration = Configuration.default.withDefaults

  implicit val decodeTenantSettings: Decoder[TenantSettings] = deriveConfiguredDecoder
}

val value = decode[Map[String, TenantSettings]](configInfo)
println(value) // Right(Map(car -> TenantSettings(Map(request1 -> key1, request2 -> ...
```

Comment: I get the following error

could not find Lazy implicit value of type io.circe.generic.extras.decoding.ConfiguredDecoder[A]
[error]   implicit final val decodeTenantSettings: Decoder[TenantSettings] = deriveConfiguredDecoder

I have wartRemover in my project that is catching this issue

Comment: If you use types in your case class that have no Decoder instance in scope the derivation fails (which is good). Sadly the error message cannot tell you exactly which type is the problem, but it's usually easy to spot. You probably added something that has no Decoder.

Comment: You could also use "circe-derivation" instead of "circe-generic" which does the same thing, but should have better error messages.

Comment: Yes actually, I did make a change. final case class TenantSettings(requesters: Map[String, String], provider: Map[String, String] = Map.empty)Map[String, String] = Map.empty) is changed to type TenantSettings = Map[String, String] 

So when I put type instead of case class, it fails although I have decoder for type . Can you tell me the issue ?

Comment: `type TenantSettings = Map[String, String]` is just a type alias and derivation makes no sense for that. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did and worked for me

```
implicit val decodeTenantSetting: Decoder[TenantSettings] = new Decoder[TenantSettings] {
      final def apply(c: HCursor): Decoder.Result[TenantSettings] =
        for {
          requesters <- c.downField("requesters").as[Map[String, String]]
        } yield {
          TenantSettings(requesters)
        }
    }

val abc = decode[Map[String, TenantSettings]](configInfo)
```